# Reserved Words in Derived Query Method Names in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a column named `nameOrSurname` and I want to have a method in my repository like `findByNameOrSurname` but I get the following exception: `org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property name found for type ...`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default [lookup method strategy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-lookup-strategies) is `CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND`, which considers first custom queries you have written. In that case if your entity that you retrieve is Customer I would have defined the HQL query by myself so that, jpa does not try to create the query by the name of the method which fails

```
    @Query(value = "FROM Customer c where c.nameOrSurname = ?1")
    List<Customer> findByNameOrSurname(String nameOrSurname);
```

Otherwise I think you are doomed to refactor your field name.

Here is just for [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) all the reserve keywords for spring JPA repository

[image]